# Facebook Account Kit conflicts with ProGuard

Tags: android, facebook, proguard, android-proguard, account-kit

We're developing an app where we're using Facebook's Account Kit.

It's been working for quite some time now but after we used ProGuard, it stopped working.

We've tried adding these lines to our proguard-rules.pro:

```
-keep class com.facebook.** { *; }
-keep class com.facebook.accountkit.** { *; }
```

Upon searching the web, most articles say that our token might be minified by ProGuard. We logged our Facebook ID and token on the release build. It seems to be okay.

[image]

Hope you can help us find the right ProGuard rules to resolve this conflict.

Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: In obfuscation, Strings won't minify. Pay attention to logcat.

Comment: Thanks, @beigirad! We'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

```
-keep class com.facebook.FacebookSdk {
   boolean isInitialized();
}

-keep class com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger {
   com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger newLogger(android.content.Context);
   void logSdkEvent(java.lang.String, java.lang.Double, android.os.Bundle);
}
```

Add to ProGuard file

for more info check this [URL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/android/configuration)

Comment: Thanks, Rakesh! But I think this is for Facebook Analytics only:

"If you are using ProGuard with certain older versions of the Account Kit SDK for Android, Account Kit may not be able to collect Facebook Analytics for your app. To ensure that your Account Kit conversion analytics remain available, you should include the following ProGuard rules."